# How to pivot rows without grouping, counting, averaging

Tags: sql, database, pivot-table

I am reworking some tables from a screwed up database. A few of the tables had the same data with different table names, and each one of them also had similar data but different column names. Anyway, this is a weird request but this has to be down like this.

I need to pivot rows up to simulate one row so I can create one record from two different tables.

I have attached a photo. The table on the left will pull a single row and the table on the left will supply 1 - n rows based on the id from the left table. I need to pivot the rows up to simulate one row and create one record with the two results.

From my checking online the pivot seems to be the way to go but it seems to want me to group or do some type of aggregating.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

```
table1 ---Produces one row
table1id | col1 | col2 | col3
1    Wow    Wee    Zee

table2 ---Produces 1 - n rows
table2id | table1id | col1 | col2 | col3
1            1        sock   cloth  sup
2            1        bal    baa    zak
3            1         x      y    fooZ
```

needs to look like this (the below is not column names, they're the result set)

```
Woo,wee,zee,sock,cloth,sup,bla,baaa,zak,x,y,fooZ
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data before and then what you want the results to look like?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using MySQL:

```
SELECT a.table1id, GROUP_CONCAT(a.col) AS col_values
FROM
(
    SELECT table1id, col1 col FROM table1 UNION ALL
    SELECT table1id, col2     FROM table1 UNION ALL
    SELECT table1id, col3     FROM table1 UNION ALL
    SELECT table1id, col1     FROM table2 UNION ALL
    SELECT table1id, col2     FROM table2 UNION ALL
    SELECT table1id, col3     FROM table2
) a
GROUP BY a.table1id
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a36c/1/0)

---

If using SQL-Server:

```
SELECT a.table1id, b.colnames
FROM table1 a
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + aa.col
        FROM
        (
            SELECT table1id, col1 col FROM table1 UNION ALL
            SELECT table1id, col2     FROM table1 UNION ALL
            SELECT table1id, col3     FROM table1 UNION ALL
            SELECT table1id, col1     FROM table2 UNION ALL
            SELECT table1id, col2     FROM table2 UNION ALL
            SELECT table1id, col3     FROM table2
         ) aa
         WHERE aa.table1id = a.table1id
         FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') AS colnames
) b
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a36c/19/0)

Comment: sqlfiddle? To sweet, I did not know that was even online. thanks